# MongoDB RSS Feed Entries, Embed the Entries in the Feed Object?

Tags: database-design, rss, schema, mongodb, feed

I am saving a reference to an RSS Feed in MongoDB, each Feed has an ever growing list of Entries.  As I'm designing my schema, I'm concerned about this statement from the [MongoDB Schema Design - Embed vs. Reference](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Schema+Design#SchemaDesign-Embedvs.Reference) Documentation:

> If the amount of data to embed is huge
>   (many megabytes), you may read the
>   limit on size of a single object.

This will surely happen if I understand the statement correctly.  So the question is, I am correct to assume that I should **not** embed the Feed Entries within a Feed because I'll eventually reach the limit on size of a single object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In designing your schema, you should be cognizant of the 4MB size limit on a single document in Mongo.

[SERVER-431](http://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-431) states:

> the 4mb limit isn't a hard limit per
>   se, its easy to change.  the reson its
>   there and we really like it is that it
>   keeps performance uniform, lets
>   drivers make some assumption about
>   input to make, and generally prevents
>   really horrible things from happening.
>
> if there is a large consensus that it
>   should change however, we certainly
>   could.

Comment: That is a very interesting statement, it appears MongoDB is opinionated software.  So if I design my schema around those constraints I can learn some conventions for modeling data in MongoDB, to limit the amount of knowlege I need to have about the database engine itself.  I like the sound of that.  In my case feed entries will have to reference feeds.  Thanks for pointing me to this.